# I can't work emulator in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-emulator

I can't work emulator in eclipse in ubuntu.I clicked window->avd manager and I selected my_device than clicked start button. But emulator is not working.
How can I do for run it?

Comment: Show some screenshots of the performed steps please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be patient. Depending on the AVD you select, API level and the hardware you are running it on, it can take a LONG time to start. If you are seeing no window appear at all, then that is a different matter. What errors do you see in the console?

Answer (score 0):

first remove your devices such as 'my_device' and then remove the folder with name '.android' in your home folder.
Then again make your own devices such as 'my_device' and try again for running the emulator.
This may solve your problem.

Comment: I solved this prpblem. thx a lot for helping.
ı wrote terminal "apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch"